# Laravel registration authentication error; how to fix?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, registration

I have encountered a problem regarding my authentication in Laravel. After running the basic authentication scaffolding, it is not possible for me to create an account using Laravel's basic login and registration layout. Everytime i fill in a name, email and password and try to create a new user I'm getting the following error:

`Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PRG05/websitemaria/vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/RegistersUsers.php on line 37`

Here is the code I'm currently working with:

**Basic RegisterController**

```
/**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

**Routes, Auth::routes is enabled**

```
//Get to the project
Route::get('/', [ProjectController::class, 'index'])->name('project');

//Enable Auth routes
Auth::routes();

//Route to function 'show' in AboutController
Route::get('/about', [AboutController::class, 'show'])->name('about');

//Route to function 'index' in HomeController
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

//Route to the functions 'index' and 'upload' in CreateController
Route::get('create', [CreateController::class, 'index'])->name('create');
Route::post('create', [CreateController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
```

**Create users table in database**

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->integer('role')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public static function create(array $validate)
    {
    }
}
```

A couple of sidenotes:

- PHPstorm seems to suggest that the create function found in the RegisterController is returning 'void',
- I have not changed any of the auth files after scaffolding except for the CreateUsersTable,
- I have checked my .ENV settings and they seem to be correct,
- Weird enough the registration and login process worked at the beginning of the project, but ultimately stopped working.

Comment: Can you edit your question, and add User model code (User.php) ?

Comment: @Koussay my apologies, I have added the User.php file.

Comment: Remove `public static function create` function from user model than try

Comment: @Luuk you need to delete the `create` function from your User model since you have another `create` method called in the laravel/ui package

Comment: Thank you all, it seemed the create function was the problem that i overlooked. I haven't the slightest clue how it got there, but i deleted it